# Upload files using a batch file not sending ftp commands?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ftp

The command I am sending is:

```
ftp -s:ftp.txt
```

Here are the contents

```
open host.com
user
pass


lcd .
cd ./public_html/path/to/dumps
binary
mput "omega.txt2"
mput "wo.txt2"
```

When I run this, it logs in just fine but then stops. How can I make it run the mput commands also once it connects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ftp` displays a confirmation prompt to start uploading and waits for your input.

Use `-i` command line switch to disable prompting:

```
ftp -i -s:ftp.txt
```

Comment: You could also include `prompt` in `ftp.txt` to turn off prompting.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug your script by connecting without it and then run each ftp command by typing in `cmd`:

```
ftp ftp.host.com
user
...
mput "wo.txt2"
```

This might help:
[Ftp](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ftp.mspx)
[Ftp subcommands](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ftp__subcommands.mspx)